# Attempt to write .vcf file using StreamWriter

Tags: c#, winforms, streamwriter

I want to write a vcard file using streamWriter class but I got this exception, what does it means and how to solve it? regards...
The exception is:
FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as disk partitions and tape drives. Avoid use of "\.\" in the path.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string contactTemplate = "BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:3.0\nN:1;mtn;;Mr.;\nFN:mtn 1\nPHOTO;VALUE=URI;TYPE=GIF:http://www.example.com/dir_photos/my_photo.gif \nTEL;TYPE=WORK,VOICE:734641900\nEND:VCARD";
            StreamWriter txt = new StreamWriter("E:\\Omar Project\\con.vcf");
            txt.Write(contactTemplate);
            txt.Close(); 
        }
```

Comment: What exception..?

Comment: FileStream will not open Win32 devices such as disk partitions and tape drives. Avoid use of "\\.\" in the path.

Comment: FYI, always google your problems first. I found the linked duplicate at the top of a google search of your exact exception message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read this warning in the [Naming Files, Paths and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN

> Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file: **CON**,
>   PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9,
>   LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, and LPT9. Also avoid
>   these names followed immediately by an extension; for example, NUL.txt
>   is not recommended. For more information, see Namespaces.

Use a different filename CON is a reserved device name

```
StreamWriter txt = new StreamWriter("E:\\Omar Project\\CONDATA.vcf");
```

Comment: Thank you sir I'll put this in my mind for future work :)